# Get value on another activity put in Edit text of list view of another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, onactivityresult

There are listview with Edittext inside of MainActivitymp3. I expect when I long click each edit text new MainActivitysentencerecording is displayed Then after I click close button value on this ( 5) is putted into MainActivitymp3.
[image]
 ***Here is MycustomerAdater class for MainActivitymp3 activity***

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
HashMap<String, String> newupdatelist = new HashMap<String, String>();
public Context context;

public static ArrayList<Song> listsong;
private DatabaseSQL datab;
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> objects) {
    this.context=context;
    this.listsong=objects;
}
...
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.song_items,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tenbai = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.text);
        viewHolder.delaytime = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delay);
        viewHolder.timeunit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeunit);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Song infor = listsong.get(position);
    viewHolder.tenbai.setText(infor.getTenbai());
    viewHolder.timeunit.setText(infor.getTimeunit());
    viewHolder.delaytime.setText(infor.getDelaytime());


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (context instanceof MainActivitymp3) {
                //play selection song
 ((MainActivitymp3)context).playMedia(listsong.get(position).getDuongdan().toString());
            }

        }
    });
    viewHolder.delaytime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  // update new value from edittext to listsong array
         listsong.get(position).setDelaytime(viewHolder.delaytime.getText().toString() );
         }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    viewHolder.delaytime.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "vi tri"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intend = new Intent(context, MainActivitysentencerecording.class);
            Activity origin = (Activity)context;
            origin.startActivityForResult(intend, 200);
       // Deleted these below lines as @David Wasser answered
          //int x=  ((MainActivitymp3)context).gio;
           // viewHolder.delaytime.setText(String.valueOf( x ));

            return true;
    });      
    return convertView;
   }

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView tenbai;
    EditText delaytime;
    TextView timeunit;
 }
 }
```

***Here is MainActivitymp3 class***

```
public class MainActivitymp3 extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...
 public  int gio;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ( new MyCustomAdapter( this, fileNames )).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == 200){
            // here comes the data from activity
            gio = data.getIntExtra("timedelaysetting",0);
            Log.d("MyAdapter", "onActivityResult  "+gio);

        }
    }
}
```

***Here is MainActivitysentencerecording activity***

```
public class MainActivitysentencerecording extends AppCompatActivity {
 ...
//close button click
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("timedelaysetting", sec);
            setResult( Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
}
```

Please give your hand to solve this issue. I'm looking for hearing from you. Thank you

Comment: You can also pass index of row that contains long pressed edittext that in adapter and then use for finding the row

Comment: Sorry ! Could you type some words with code for answering. I can't get your point

Comment: Use eventbus library for passing data to anywhere from anywhere in the application.!
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Comment: @onur taskin. It worked for me.  I get value and index of row then update array list of MyCustomAdapter. After that Listview is set new MyCustomAdapter . Thank you for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how launching one `Activity` from another works. In your longclick listener you have this code:

```
origin.startActivityForResult(intend, 200);
int x=  ((MainActivitymp3)context).gio;
viewHolder.delaytime.setText(String.valueOf( x ));
```

This implies that you think when you call `startActivityForResult()` that control is passed immediately to `MainActivitysentencerecording` and that the next line of code (`int x=  ((MainActivitymp3)context).gio;`) is executed only after `MainActivitysentencerecording` completes and finishes.

That isn't how it works. When you call `startActivityForResult()` you are just asking the Android framework to please launch the target `Activity` (in this case `MainActivitysentencerecording`) **when the Android framework regains control**. The next few lines of code are executed immediately after the call to `startActivityForResult()` before `MainActivitysentencerecording` is even launched and shown to the user.

You need to just `return` after calling `startActivityForResult()` and the Android framework will then regain control and launch `MainActivitysentencerecording`. When that `Activity` completes, the Android framework will call `MainActivitymp3.onActivityResult()`. This happens asynchronously and much later than you think. You can only update your UI **after** `onActivityResult()` is called.

Comment: Waseer Thank you for your lesson. You are right . And I stop use int x=  ((MainActivitymp3)context).gio;
viewHolder.delaytime.setText(String.valueOf( x )); As you said. However I do not understand method MainActivitymp3.onActivityResult() you mentioned. Could you help me more and detail? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Please search the web for a tutorial about how to use `startActivityForResult()`. I can't explain that to you in an answer and that isn't what Stackoverflow is for.